# In what sense are "projecting" and "taking sections" of polytopes dual operations?

Tags: geometry, duality-theorems, polytopes, projection, cross-sections

It seems to be folklore that *projecting* and *taking sections* of polytopes are somehow "dual operations" (e.g. explicitly noted in the abstract of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.4150.pdf) paper, or suggested by [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/309507/108884) to an MO question of mine). But I do not know the exact formal meaning of this statement.

A *polytope* $P\subset\Bbb R^n$ is the convex hull of finitely many points. Let $V\subset\Bbb R^n$ be an affine subspace. Denote by $\pi_V$ the *orthogonal projection* onto $V$.

> - The *section* of $P$ along $V$ is the polytope $P\cap V$.
> - The *projection* of $P$ onto $V$ is the polytope $\pi_V P$.

Can someone explain to me, in what sense these operations are **dual** to each other? I am familiar with dual polytopes, and I assume it has something to do with these. I am not certain whether the "dual operations" make use of the same affine subspace $V$.

Comment: I believe it's a different duality, a more linear-algebraic one. Here's a very naive take, as a comment since it doesn't come close to being a full answer: you say 'the orthogonal projection onto $V$', but there are many different $V$ with isomorphic orthogonal projections; just 'parallel transport' $V$ along itself.  This suggests that when we talk about projecting 'onto' $V$, what we really mean is projecting _along_ the dual $V^{\perp}$ of $V$ - that is to say, its direction.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I think the kind of duality is indeed a geometric one. At least this is suggested by [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/309507/108884) to an MO question of mine. I felt it was more appropriate to ask the details as a separate MSE question.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea here is that of lattice inspections. You could consider the different Delone cells of the lattice and its Voronoi cell. By definition according cell complexes are vice versas duals.

But if you would embed your lattice in a higher dimensional regular one, you would observe that the various lower dimensional Delone cells just occur as different layerwise sections of higher dimensional lattice polytopes (cells). And likewise you get that the lower dimensional Voronoi cell is obtained as the projection of that very lattice polytope.

For instance the Delone cells of (triangular) lattice $A_2$ are triangles, half of those pointing up, half of those pointing down. The Voronoi cell is the regular hexagon. - The triangular tiling and the hexagonal one clearly are vice versas duals. - But when embeding $A_2$ into (cubical) lattice $BC_3$, you see that those triangles occur as vertex layer sections of those cubes, while the hexagon is the projection of the cube with respect to the orthogonal direction of the chosen vertex layers.

--- rk